# r showing shape file incorrectly while scaling up the dimensions in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, shapefile

I am trying to open world  map and to increase its dimension to look only on Europe.When I plot all map in ggplot?, there is no problem
:

```
shape <- readOGR(dsn = "/home/user/QGis/50m_physical", layer = "ne_50m_land")
map_2 <- ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data = shape, 
             aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
             colour = "black", 
             fill = NA)
```

[image]

When I try to increase dimensions,

```
shape <- readOGR(dsn = "/home/user/QGis/50m_physical", layer = "ne_50m_land")
map_2 <- ggplot() + 
         geom_polygon(data = shape, 
             aes(x = long, 
                 y = lat, 
                 group = group), 
                 colour = "black", 
             fill = NA)+
         scale_x_continuous(name="Longitude", limits=c(-40, 90))+
         scale_y_continuous(name="Latitude", limits=c(30, 80))
```

it shows me some additional lines:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your example, since I do not have the data.
However I suspect that replacing

```
scale_x_continuous(name="Longitude", limits=c(-40, 90))+
scale_y_continuous(name="Latitude", limits=c(30, 80))
```

with

```
coord_cartesian(xlim =c(-40, 90), ylim = c(30, 80))
```

fixes the problem